# Is it possible to create a Monero miner in Python?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, mining-theory

I would like to create a Python based Monero miner. I know that using Python for mining will likely be slow, but this is just for experimental purposes. Thanks.

Comment: I could swear someone did it.  They did it just for grins & giggles, and said it was so slow you could time it on a sundial.

Comment: Do you know who did it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible to make a miner using Python. There are several ways this can be accomplished and depends on what you want to achieve.

At it's bare minimum you would need to have the hashing algorithm, `cn_slow_hash`, implemented in Python. An example library that exposes this is [here](https://github.com/ph4r05/py-cryptonight). The rest will boil down to what kind of miner you want to create. You could create a stratum based miner to work with a pool or you could create a solo miner talking directly with a Monero node via it's RPC interface.

I suggest first learning about the actual process of mining and then look at the source code of existing miner implementations.