# What is the best Python library for hashing Cryptonight?

Tags: cryptonight, source, python, monero-mining, library

What is the best Python library for hashing Cryptonight hashes and building mining software?

Comment: Really a duplicate of https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10787/is-it-possible-to-create-a-monero-miner-in-python but asking opinionated question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, the best Python library for hashing CryptoNight is still the [py-cryptonight](https://github.com/ph4r05/py-cryptonight), a Python CryptoNight implementation. This library has the crypto stuff in C/C++ (lifted straight from the Monero code base) and compiled into the Python library.

Comment: To be clear, this library is not "fully" Python, the crypto stuff is in C/C++ (lifted straight from the Monero code base) and compiled into the Python library. Also, it is up-to-date, as it has the current CNv2 implemented, so the remark of not being updated for months is misleading.

Comment: My apologies, it actually *doesn't* support CNv2. I created a PR for it though.

Comment: Anyway, the question is about CN and not CNv2.